# Как забрать значения через jquery в каждом блоке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть множество блоков с классом row. Каждый блок содержит два элемента (название и цена).

Мне нужно вытащить все значения из блоков с классом active-row и все значения добавить в блок с классом all-text.

Проблема в том, что у меня забирается только одно значение, а должны - все.

Вот мой пример кода:

```js
$.each($('.active-row'), function() {
  var uslugi = $(this).find('.name').text() + $(this).find('.price').text();

  $('.all-text').text(uslugi);


});
```

```css
.all-text {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="name">
    Машина
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row active-row">
  <div class="name">
    Коляска
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row active-row">
  <div class="name">
    Велосипед
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row active-row">
  <div class="name">
    Машина
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="name">
    Машина
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>

<div class="all-text">

</div>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var uslugi = '';
$.each($('.active-row'), function() {
  uslugi += $(this).find('.name').text() + $(this).find('.price').text();
});
$('.all-text').text(uslugi);
```

```css
.all-text {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="name">
    Машина
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row active-row">
  <div class="name">
    Коляска
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row active-row">
  <div class="name">
    Велосипед
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row active-row">
  <div class="name">
    Машина
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="name">
    Машина
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    1250
  </div>
</div>

<div class="all-text">

</div>
```